# Does Non fungible Tokens need more RAM?

Tags: tokens, ram-allocation, cpu, nonfungible

Non fungible tokens with tracability need a table that need space and Non fungible tokens also need more computation as we need to  have  **mint** ,**burn** ,**create** and **issue** abi actions.

In my opinion surely they need  greater RAM, How do I calculate the RAM that I need  for my contract that contains NFT.

Is there any alternative way to reduce cost!

Answer (score 1):

In fungible tokens you track number of tokens per an account.

In non-fungible tokens you track individual token per account.

The latter is the only way to do non-fungible tokens - you need to track an individual token, as it would not be non-fungible otherwise.

You cannot compress the memory cost beyond `account:token id` pair, so there is no way to reduce the cost beyond raw RAM consumption.

Comment: This is not an answer related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no any tool that provided by eos to calculate how much RAM your contract need but if you know exactly how much RAM needed than this site https://www.eosrp.io/ will definitely help you out.To calculate RAM for contract i think to go on mainnet or testnet and test over there to checkout usage of RAM will be best way.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but reads a lot like an advertisement of the third party site. However, the original question was not exact and have different points intervened.

Comment: I am not advertising any third party over here i just tried to give my openion